# Using Orca to modify a Cisco Anyconnect MSI installer file

Tags: client, windows-installer, vpn, orca

I am currently in the process of installing Cisco anyconnect on several windows machines. I would   like to make this installation as "hands off" as possible for the end users. I have the msi file to install anyconnect only, with no features such as host scan, telemetry, etc. enabled. What I would like to accomplish is to remove some of the setting check boxes or have them correctly set so that the user does not have to do anything except for install, click yes, and accept the license agreement. Is this possible using Orca to modify the MSI file? There are only 3 features you can change in the settings menu of Anyconnect. The checkboxes are as follows:

1. Enable automatic certificate selection
2. Allow (LAN) access when using VPN (if configured)
3. Block connections to untrusted servers

Comment: if allowed by the vendor, you can also modify the MSI directly and edit the properties in Property table. i.e. if you want an option to be selected you must make sure the property is present in Property table and has a value in it, if you want the option to not be selected by default make sure the property is not in the table(delete it) and also check if there are any "Set Property" custom actions that might try to initialize it based on other user actions/machine parameters

Answer (score 0):

Orca can edit MSI's.  It can also create transforms.  The checkboxes have properties that likely can be passed at the command line:

```
msiexec /I foo.msi ALLOWLANACCESWHENUSINGVPN=1
```

or if you create a transform that sets ALLOWLANACCESSWHENSUINGVPN=1 you could say:

```
msiexec /I foo.msi TRANSFORMS=mytransform.mst
```

The name of the property and whether it can be passed at the command line depends on how the installer was created.